# Exception while running number of queries concurrently on DB2

Tags: db2

We are testing an application specific Design where we need to show progressive counts after firing many queries simultaneously.

When we are firing a single query, we are successfully able to get Results Asynchronously.

But, when we are firing 3-4 queries simultaneously, after a significant amount of time & after getting some records for each query
we are getting an exception which states

**“com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -1218, SQLSTATE: 57011, SQLERRMC: 4099”**

Because of this, all the queries fired do not get executed completely.

There is no problem if these queries are fired one by one. (query2 starts executing after query1 completes & so on)

After looking for this SQLCODE in Control Center we found out the details which are,

---

SQL1218N  There are no pages currently available in bufferpool

```
  "<buffpool-num>".
```

Explanation:

All of the pages in the bufferpool are currently being used. A request
to use another page failed.

The statement may be successful if executed again. If this error occurs
frequently, some or all of the following actions may prevent further
failures:

1. increase the bufferpool size
2. decrease the maximum number of database agents and/or connections
3. decrease the maximum degree of parallelism
4. decrease the prefetch size for table spaces that are in this

   bufferpool
5. move some table spaces into other bufferpools.

   sqlcode: -1218

   sqlstate: 57011

---

On our DB instance, we already had a buffer pool of 32K page size & even after creating another buffer pool
of 32K, the problem persists.

Can anyone kindly help us in solving the problem.

Thanks & Regards,

Ravindra Jain

Answer (score 1):

The pagesize of a bufferpool has to match the pagesize of the tablespaces it is associated with.  Do all of your tablespaces use 32K pages?  You should check whether there is a different bufferpool that is running out of pages.  10,000 pages should be more than enough to avoid the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is your transactions are not issueing "commits" so there is buildup of uncommited data in the buffer pools.

Also 32K seems very small for current hardware ( Since DB2 can handle CLOBs and BLOBs of several megabytes) 32MB or more would be more appropriate for a bufferpool size.

Answer (score 0):

We are committing after each record is inserted/updated.
So, redo log is not a problem. (buffer pool will never be over-flooded).

32K is the page size of the buffer pool & buffer pool contains 10000 pages.
So, are these configurations appropriate for the buffer pool?